# Class files present in the referenced libraries but eclipse maven not recognizing it while doing build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

[image: updateBulkEdit and DistributionOrderHeader are present in the Referenced Libraries.]

But even then the maven build is unable to find those classes while doing maven build.
It says cannot find symbol.
But the editor is not throwing any compilation problems. It is only the maven build which is not referring to the jar which is imported to the Referenced libraries.

Comment: So, is this JAR listed in the `<dependencies>` section of your POM (not the `<dependencyManagement>` section?

Comment: I was using wrong maven version of jar.